# ReflectionClass doesn't exist in PHP 5.3 - Sapphire Crashing

Tags: php, silverstripe

A website of ours that has been working for 6 years just started crashing yesterday. Activating the errors, I find out that there is an error with Sapphire.

[image]

That class is supposed to exist in PHP 5.3. And still, the error says it doesnt.

Here is the code creating the error (from the Sapphire core files, don't want to ever modify that.)

[image]

So the question is, can my host have desactivated that class from PHP? What can I do to fix the error? I can't really update sapphire, since it's being used inside a CMS (Silverstripe version 2.4.5) and wouldn't risk updating Silverstripe (the site has been known to be unstable).

UPDATE:

Just figured that the ReflectionClass does exists (it throws me an error from ReflectionClass) so it's the $class variable that is not what ReflectionClass expects.

UPDATE 2:

Var_dump of $class gives

```
string(22) "GoogleSitemapDecorator" string(9) "Hierarchy" NULL NULL
```

var_dump of $args gives

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(22) "GoogleSitemapDecorator" } array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "Hierarchy" } array(2) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> float(0) } array(2) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> float(0) }
```

Comment: Well, what is `var_dump($class)`? What's `var_dump($args);`?

Comment: ..so my final question is if `GoogleSitemapDecorator` exists?

Comment: It seems to exist. I tested and the 4 results are coming from 4 separated calls to the function. I can split them up with an echo after the dump (that I made on line 87 of the file.) Still searching!

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it (has not) caught a *`ReflectionException`*, which means it's an exception thrown by the `ReflectionClass` class. The message of this exception is *"Class does not exist"*. The stack trace shows that you're calling

```
ReflectionClass->__construct('')
```

meaning you're passing `''` as the argument to `new ReflectionClass`. Of course, the class `''` probably indeed does not exist.

In other words, `$class` contains the wrong value.

Comment: If I try to put an if around the $reflector and its return (if $class == "") it throws me another error. Fatal error: __clone method called on non-object in /services/webpages/xxxxx/public/sapphire/core/Object.php on line 143

Answer (score 0):

This was asked so many years ago. But, for alerting people who are asking themselves the same question, it is known that `ReflexionClass` exists in PHP 5.3. It is more, I've recently used it for developing a IoC/DI Container compatible with PHP 5.3.

Fredy31 had a wrong value for `$class`.